# Integrating factor and differential 1-forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I am working on the following exercise:

> The function $f$ is called an *integrating factor* for the 1-form $\omega$ if $f({\bf x}) \neq 0$ for all $\bf x$ and $d(f\omega) = 0$. If the 1-form $\omega$ has an integrating factor, show that $\omega \wedge d\omega = 0$.

I am stuck here... I got $$d(f\omega) = df \wedge \omega + f \wedge d\omega = df \wedge \omega + f\ d\omega = 0$$ but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere. I also tried expanding this further (using the definition of $df$), but this gets quite ugly soon and didn't help either. The same goes for $\omega \wedge d\omega$.

Comment: Consider $\omega \wedge d\omega = \Omega$. Multiply it by $f$ ($f \neq 0$) and use your equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That last equation gives you
$$d\omega = -(1/f) df\wedge\omega. $$
Then you have
$$\omega \wedge d\omega = -(1/f)\omega\wedge df \wedge \omega = (1/f)\omega\wedge\omega \wedge df = 0.$$
This is because the wedge product of any form with itself is zero.  Notice that it is critical that $f$ be zero-free, or the taking of the reciprocal breaks everything.

Comment: Pay attention to the signi -.

Comment: I think it should be $d\omega = -(1/f) df\wedge\omega$ (but that makes no difference). Thanks, working with differential forms I seem to forget that division exists.

Answer (score 0):

If d(f w)=0 it implies that f w = d l (Pointcaré's lemma), where l is an scalar function. Therefore w= f^-1 d l. Taking the exterior derivative in both sides we get 
dw= - f^-2 df \wedge dl + 0 = - f^-1 df \wedge w.

And finally

w \wedge dw= - f^-1 w \wedge df \wedge w =0, qed.

Comment: See this introductory note about [posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.